# How to send a JSON file on an URL in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, request, middleware

I have a JSON:

```
url = 'https://your_php_server_url.com/php_endpoint'
payload = {
  'full_name': the_name,
  'phone_number': the_phone,
}
```

How can I send the json using POST in python?

Comment: To send json have to convert object to string. import json -> json.dumps(your_json)

Comment: Please paste your code here and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python side, you can use [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org//en/master/) library:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://your_php_server_url.com/php_endpoint'
payload = {
  'full_name': the_name,
  'phone_number': the_phone,
}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
print(r.text)
```